# How to insert the configuration.nix file inside my dot files?

Tags: symlink, configuration-files, nixos, dotfiles

I am creating my dot files following this [tutorial](https://github.com/daviwil/emacs-from-scratch/blob/master/show-notes/Dotfiles-02.org). It successfully works for `emacs.d`.

Since I am using NixOS, I tried doing exactly the same steps with symlink creation for the `configuration.nix` file. Thus, I did:

1 - On terminal:

```sh
[pedro@system:/etc/nixos]$ sudo mv /etc/nixos/configuration.nix ~/.dotfiles/
```

2 - Then:

```
[pedro@system:/etc/nixos]$ ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/configuration.nix configuration.nix~
```

3 - It seems to work fine, as I do:

```
[pedro@system:/etc/nixos]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec  1 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 root root 4096 Dec  1 22:00 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   39 Dec  1 21:41 configuration.nix~ -> /home/pedro/.dotfiles/configuration.nix
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  842 Nov 12 17:40 hardware-configuration.nix
```

After doing some editions and saving the changes, I can't do `nixos-rebuild switch`, though. It throws an error:

```
[pedro@system:/etc/nixos]$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch 
warning: Nix search path entry '/etc/nixos/configuration.nix' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixos-config' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I), at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixos/default.nix:1:60
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
building Nix...
warning: Nix search path entry '/etc/nixos/configuration.nix' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixos-config' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I), at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixos/default.nix:1:60
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
building the system configuration...
warning: Nix search path entry '/etc/nixos/configuration.nix' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixos-config' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I), at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixos/default.nix:1:60
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

The `~` after `configuration.nix~` might be the problem here. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Step 2 seems to have cause the issue here: The symlink should be called `configuration.nix` not `configuration.nix~` as you have noticed.

You could fix this by running `mv configuration.nix~ configuration.nix` in the `/etc/nixos` folder which would rename `configuration.nix~` to the correct `configuration.nix`.